# Como Puedo Separar una palabra letra por letra en python

Tags: python

Hola quiero ingresar una palabra con un input y que la separe el programa letra por letra en una lista:

```
palabra = "agua"
resultado = ['a', 'g', 'u', 'a']
```

Usé el método `Split`, pero no funcionó (trae toda la palabra)

```
palabra = "agua fria"
resultado = ['agua',' ','fria']
```

No sirve así, tiene que ser letra por letra

```
palabra = "agua fria"
resultado = ['a','g','u','a','','f','r','i','a']
```

Comment: `list(palabra)`

Comment: Estudia primero [Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/es/3.8/tutorial/index.html)

Answer (score 2):

en python, las palabras son simplemente listas de Strings.
es decir, si haces palabra = "agua", ya puedes separarla letra por letra, pues ya es de la forma ["a", "g", "u", "a"], solo que lo muestra todo junto porque en primera instancia lo toma como String.

como prueba, puedes correr esto en python:

```
palabra = "agua"
print(palabra[0])
print(palabra[1])
print(palabra[2])
print(palabra[3])
```

es decir, declaramos un string ("agua") pero inmediatamente ya se podía leer como lista.

por lo que lo único que debes hacer, es decirle a python que en vez de tomarlo como String, que lo tome como lista.

```
palabra = "agua"
palabra = list(palabra)
print(palabra)
```

Espero esto te sirva y hayas aprendido un poco más ;)

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Procura evitar responder a preguntas de baja calidad o que no demuestren que se ha intentado hacer algo. Lee [answer], en especial la sección _Contesta preguntas bien formadas_.

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que renombrar la palabra y convertirla en una lista:

```
palabra= "agua"
palabra=list(palabra)
print(palabra)
```

Answer (score 0):

Existen varias formas de separar palabras letra por letra en `python`, entre ellas esta la que te ence#o el compa#ero en su respuesta. Puedes tambien hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```
def main():
    user_response = input('Write a word: ')
    # Si deseas recorrer la palabra puedes hacer esto
    for char in user_response: # los strings son iterables
        print(char)
    """Output
    Write a word: hello world
    h
    e
    l
    l
    o

    w
    o
    r
    l
    d"""
    # Si lo que deseas es simplemente obtener el arreglo para procesarlo o lo que sea puedes hacer lo siguiente:
    word_chars = list(user_response)
    print(word_chars)
    """Output
    Write a word: hi
    ['h', 'i']"""

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Si le respondes con asyncio y clases para sacar letra por letra de una palabra....tienes dos problemas: uno que respondes a una pregunta pobre y sin desarrollo por parte del que pregunta, y dos una respuesta, que aunque pueda ser valida, es totalmente desproporcionada e innecesariamente compleja. Como bien apunta @padaleiana pasate por https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer para saber como responder correctamente

Comment: Esta bien... Lo tomare en cuenta. Ya edito mi respuesta